# Unidentified error with certain cells values causing #value! error with MATCH formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Can you please assist me in trying to identify what is wrong with  certains values causing a formula that works fine on the vast majority of cells to returns a #value! error?

```
=MATCH(LEFT([@ID],FIND("~",[@ID])-1) & "|" &[@Original],V1_TTK_strings[Real ID],0)
```

Example of value where the formula fails:

```
While the internet undoubtedly presents fantastic opportunities for children, it is equally clear that there is a real opportunity for children to be put at risk by their exposure to material and/or individuals which may be harmful.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MATCH`can only handle texts up to 255 characters. As your texts are longer, you do not get a hit.

Instead, use this formula:

```
=MATCH(TRUE,(LEFT([@ID],FIND("~",[@ID])-1)&"|"&[@Original])=V1_TTK_strings[Real ID],0)
```

You need to enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>.